# my Raspberry Pi 3B+ stops booting some time after work

Tags: pi-3b+

my Raspberry Pi 3B+ stops booting some time after work.  Different manifestations: either only the red LED flashes, or the green one blinks 4 times. This starts to show up after I reboot the board. And this is solved by the fact that I overwrite the RPi Lite x64 image to the same SD card. Yesterday I tried to restart the board about 7 times on an absolutely clean image and it worked properly. The board worked for about 20 hours, I decided to restart it again and it stopped starting again. I have only a DVBT stick connected to the board via a USB hub for receiving ADS-B signals. 32 GB SD card, Class 10

Comment: Are you using the official 5.1V 2.5A power supply?

Comment: @CoderMike yes.

Comment: 4 flashes: `Note that 4 flashes could be an indication of a more or less broken SD-card connector. If Databit 1 is connected, but one of the other three Databits doesn't make contact, so the SD-card only works in 1-bit (SPI) mode, then this will lead to the four flashes error! Check if all pins of your card holder make good contact with the card!` - https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151

Comment: Basically you haven't done anything except re-image the same SD card, nothing else has changed. Try a different SD card. Try running from a USB thumb drive (the 3B+ will boot from USB without you needing to do anything)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Pi is behaving like this due to overheating. Check your Raspberry Pi's temperature with the following command.
`vcgencmd measure_temp`